# Font size for all the pages

Tags: java, jquery, spring-mvc

I am quite new to Spring and Web Applications.

I create object containing font size in my controller and then I add it to the model.

```
private String fontSize = "24";

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public final ModelAndView mainGet(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException {

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("home");
    model.addObject("fontSize", fontSize);

    return model;
}
```

I pass it to the JSP and there I set the font size using jQuery. 
In the application I have buttons to change the font size...everything works, but when I refresh or change the page these settings are lost.

How can I save this value in the model? Should I do the post call through AJAX every time I change the size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no auto-setup of the back-and-forth between server and client. If you make a change on the client, say using jQuery, and you wish to persist that change, you have to store the value somewhere. You can do that on the server side, e.g., in a database of preferences, or in the servlet container's session. Or, you can do it on the client side, e.g., using local storage or cookies. You could even store it as part of a state object in your HTML, and pass the state object around with you as you navigate the site.

The right place to store it depends on your use case and the design of your system. You could certainly use AJAX to post the updated value each time the user makes a change, which means you'll need a method to handle it and persist the value somewhere, as in the following (untested) code.:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/prefs/fontSize", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public void putFontSize(@RequestBody String fontSize)
        throws ServletException {
    // persist fontSize here. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okey, I managed it...

I downloaded jQuery Cookie Plugin, I think the best way to save this value is to do that using a cookie (or maybe it's just the easiest way).

This is the link to the plugin I've used:

[jQuery Cookie Plugin](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/)